# is possible to open a new codeigniter view in a new window

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need to know if it is possible to load a codeigniter view in a new window?

i need to send data to the view like this

```
$this->load->view('pdfview', $data);
```

but i want this view open in a new window or tab

Hello

i need to know if it is possible to load a codeigniter view in a new window?

i need to send data to the view like this

```
$this->load->view('pdfview', $data);
```

but i want this view open in a new window or tab

Comment: to open new window you need to user anchor() function of codeigniter as shown below,

<?php echo anchor($url, $title, array('target' => '_blank'))); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the page on click with anchor tag and put target as "blank" like

```
<a href="mydomain/controller/function" target="_blank">Goto Page</a>
```

Comment: how can i pass the data doing that?

Comment: Which data you want to pass

Comment: @user1910232 as GET or POST parameters, probably

Comment: because in main view i have a submit button, when i click it controller process the form and send all the form information to this new view that i want to open in new window

Comment: $data..??if you redirect youyr anchor tag to your function that contains $this->load->view('pdfview', $data); will automatically pass the data

Answer (score 0):

Opening new window is not server-side operation (which is PHP) - it's client-side. You should just add target to your `<a>` tag.

Comment: thought there is a way to load the codeigniter view in new window

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a server-side language (PHP) to control client-side behavior (forcing a new browser window for a hyperlink).

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling your controller/view? Obviously from a link on your site.

On that link add a target="_blank" attribute.

```
Eg: <a href="pdf/view/12" target="_blank">View PDF</a>
```

User clicks on it, it opens a new window.